# Interaction terms in within.between model using function wbm() from the package 'panelr'

Tags: package, panel, interaction

I'm doing a within-between model using the function wbm() from the package 'panelr'. However, my models have 2 interaction terms, so I wanna make sure I'm implementing them in a proper way. Following this link (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/panelr/vignettes/wbm.html), it seems the interaction terms should be include in the 3rd part of the formula, named 'cross_kev_interactions':

```
dependent ~ time_varying | time_invariant | cross_lev_interactions + (random_slopes | id)
```

Then, I guess the resulting especification for my model would be (I just got 1 time-invariant variable ('manco'):

```
model <- wbm(efic ~ faf + mun_tur + distancia + ideo | manco | faf*alidep + faf*alixun, data = datos)
```

I wanna make sure this is the right way to implement those interaction terms and, if not, how I sould do it.